# Create a Bitmap (.NET) from HBITMAP

Tags: c++-cli, type-conversion, intptr, hbitmap

I'm using C++/CLI and I have a raw `HBITMAP` called `hStrip`, I have to display this in a `PictureBox`, so I found the following function `System::Drawing::Image::FromHbitmap`, however this takes `IntPtr` and I wondered if I need to convert my raw `HBITMAP` to `IntPtr` before passing it in or if I could get away passing it in like this?

If I need to convert, how should I convert?  I haven't really found the conversion this way.  I did find it the other way though.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Is it failing in any of those cases?

Comment: @Attila no I haven't tried it, because my application is too complex to simply try it atm. Since they are essentially different types, I'm just assuming incompatibilty, but maybe my assumption is wrong

Comment: HBITMAP is a handle, which is effectivly an IntPtr.

Comment: As Mare said, the reason for `IntPtr` is to represent arbitrary low-level pointers (instead of .NET handles and references).  Instead of creating a type for each possible pointer combinations (which would be impossible anyway), the .NET API just uses the `IntPtr` type to represent arbitrary pointers (most usually handles)

Comment: Handles of different types are just bitpatterns of generally same size. Or always less than size of pointer (intptr is an integer type sufficient to represent the bits of a pointer value). So just `reinterpret_cast` if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple cast gets the job done:

```
HBITMAP hBmp = NULL;
// Assign hBmp
//...
Bitmap^ bmp = Bitmap::FromHbitmap((IntPtr)hBmp);
DeleteObject(hBmp);  // okay to destroy now
```